# Disable or remove vendor routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

After installing one package using composer, the service creating a route dynamically. I am concern about its security. May be deleting `routes.php` from the vendor source would solve the issue. But is there any way to remove or disable that route or any route created by any particular vendor without touching the vendor folder?

Example in a package: https://github.com/matriphe/laravel-imageupload/blob/master/src/routes.php

Comment: What exactly is that route? And which package is doing that?

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of is to reroute it like this:

```
Route::any('matriphe/imageupload', function()
{
    return abort(404);
});
```